# Running for-loop and pause for api call

Tags: javascript

I am using `node v10.15.3` and I am trying to pause `4 seconds` to make api calls.

I tried the following:

```js
let arr = ["Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4"]


function callApi() {
  console.log("start - " + new Date().toString());
  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      setTimeout(async() => {
        // here usually comes the api call
        await console.log(arr[index]);
        await console.log(new Date().toString());
      }, 4000);
    })(i);
  }
  console.log("end - " + new Date().toString());
}

callApi()
```

As you can see from the output, first the message `start` and `end` are the output and then the `for-loop` is run. However, I would like to wait betweend every function run 4 seconds and get the following ouput:

```
start - Sun Sep 08 2019 13:28:03
Product 1
Sun Sep 08 2019 13:32:07
Product 2
Sun Sep 08 2019 13:36:07
Product 3
Sun Sep 08 2019 13:40:07
Product 4
Sun Sep 08 2019 13:44:07
end - Sun Sep 08 2019 13:28:03
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That's kinda convoluted, why not just `await` in the body of the `for` loop, without the inner function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are right! Thx for your reply! I kindly ask you to add your answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout(..., 4000)` - in each iteration of the loop you call `setTimeout` with different functions, but the same delay, so all four functions are scheduled to run at the same time, 4 seconds from now.

Instead, try: `setTimeout(..., 4000 * (index + 1))`.

Alternatively, since you're using `await` already, you could write this more clearly by wrapping `setTimeout` in a `Promise`:

```js
let arr = ["Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4"]

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function callApi() {
  console.log("start - " + new Date().toString());
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    await sleep(4000);
    console.log(arr[i]);
    console.log(new Date().toString());
  }
  console.log("end - " + new Date().toString());
}

callApi()
```

Side note: `await` has no effect when used with `console.log`, as the latter does not return a `Promise` (maybe you previously had network-related code that did use promises here and it's just a leftover?).

Comment: You can create a code snippet on SO [`How to create a code snippet`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

It would probably make more sense to just `await` in the `for` loop body:

```js
let arr = ["Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4"];
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function callApi() {
  for (const item of arr) {
    await delay(2000); // example API call
    console.log(item);
  }
}

callApi()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `async` function is the one function that has the ability to stop executing code and `await` the resolving of an asynchronous task, usually a promise. Since your `for loop` is located in the outer function (which is not async) it will finish the loop without awaiting anything and simply start several independent `setTimeout`s.

To fix your function rewrite it similar to this:

```
  async function callApi() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
      // here usually comes the api call
      await request(i)
    }
  }

  function request(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
        resolve();
      }, 4000);
    }
  }
```

The functionality behind 'pausing' a function is called `generators` in case you want to read up on how it works.